Clogging pipe from kitchen sink
This pipe (the one running though the center of the image with the elbows) is coming from my kitchen and running down into the basement floor here (the vertical part goes to the floor) I have had a clog in this pipe before and managed to snake it out from the sink, Well, it clogged again (and I dont put much down there at all). actually this whole waste line was clogged when I bought the house. and most of it was replaced except this portion.. ugh.
Anyway, I went down to see if I could feel weight where the clog might be this time again and noticed that, at this point where the elbows are, there is a dip in the pipe (at least 2 inches) before it then gets to the 90deg that goes to the floor. that is, the input into the 90deg into the floor is higher than the output of the 45deg by around 2 inches, so that section of pipe ends up filling before it ever flows out. Is that normal? or is this the cause of my clog issue with what little I put down the sink just always getting stuck here?
If this is not how it is supposed to be and likely my problem, what is the best approach to fix it? is it sufficient to just cut 2.5 insh or so from the vertical section and rejoin the pipe? (after cleaning it out)

It all runs on gravity, so yes indeed, if the pipe slopes the wrong way, it will end up full of crap and clog up...
I'd expect to see some form of fastening on these pipes, but I don't see any. The elbow in front of the photo looks like it's sagging a bit, perhaps all you have to do is hang it from the beams to prop it a little bit higher and restore the proper slope on the other pipe... That would be the first thing to check. Of course you'll have to check whether the upstream pipes still have the proper slope.

Minimum allowed slope around here (France) is 1% so 1cm/m, but that's the absolute minimum, here you have room for more so you should use it.
Personally I would redo the whole thing, it's just 2 elbows, 2 couplings and a bit of pipe... because elbow (4) is useless and wastes a lot of height.
So, from (1) which is whatever is upstream, I'd either go diagonal in the room and direct to elbow 5... or keep pipe 2, replace elbow 3 with a new rotated so that elbow 4 can be removed and it goes directly to elbow 5. Basically, follow the white arrow:

Since there is a beam, you'll have the best slope in pipe 2 if it rests on top of the beam, and the other pipe won't cause clearance problems because it'll be hidden behind the beam.

yea, I just wanted to make sure there wasnt any weird "trap" just before it heads to the floor. The rest of the pipe is barely sloped even now actually so I'm not going to get 2 inches I dont think but I might go around and look. There is a fastener on the next joist over, so it is being hung and supposedly leveled/sloped properly. so, would you just measure it out and  drop 2-2.5 inches off the vertical to give myself more slope?

Not sure of the exact, but all horizontal pipes should have a down slope about ~1/4 inch per foot.

@Bastiat yes if there's no other way you can just cut the vertical part and insert a fitting, if the rest of the pipe is barely sloped you can also add some slope there while you're at it, and adjust the fastener. I edited the answer.

@bobflux awesome, thanks very much. All makes sense, just wanted to double check as I'm not actually a plumber and it was actually a plumber that replaced some of the rest of this pipe before already.

You're welcome! I have noticed that plumbers sometimes are a bit too fond of elbows and nicely laid out pipes at right angles, sometimes at the cost of performance... Whereas the good old straight line with maximum slope may not look as "professional" but on the other hand... it never clogs...
